# TestNG change class extension efficently?

Tags: testng

I have some tests that have to test features with either an Admin account or a Member account. At the moment, I have two different functions for logging in, one for each account, and I have the classes extend from these login tests for ease.

My question is if there's an efficient way of changing class extensions on TestNG without just rewriting what the class extends from? I don't mind changing the layout of the other files if it's the better option.

Example of the current structure:

```
public class MemberLogin {
 (Login information)
}

public class AdminLogin {
 (Login information)
}

public class TestFeature extends (blank)Login {
 (Test feature)
}
```

Comment: Is there anything different between the 2 account types, besides the credentials? Something that requires a specific different logic for each account type? If not, why not just [parametrize](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters) the information and have just one class?

Comment: TestFeature really shouldn't extend Login. You should pass in the creds as Morfic suggested. You really shouldn't need two log in functions, one for member and one for admin... I'm assuming you are just using a username and password for both and there's no real difference in the login process... only the access level after login.

Comment: Took me a second to get it set up with IntelliJ, but this is actually working very well! I'm just starting to learn all the features for TestNG so didn't even know this was a thing that can be used. Thanks!